# Dynamic choices in model CharField choices

Tags: django, django-models

This document shows an example of how to declare a model CharField with choices [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/)

```
class Student(models.Model):
    FRESHMAN = 'FR'
    SOPHOMORE = 'SO'
    JUNIOR = 'JR'
    SENIOR = 'SR'
    GRADUATE = 'GR'
    YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = [
        (FRESHMAN, 'Freshman'),
        (SOPHOMORE, 'Sophomore'),
        (JUNIOR, 'Junior'),
        (SENIOR, 'Senior'),
        (GRADUATE, 'Graduate'),
    ]
    year_in_school = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES,
        default=FRESHMAN,
    )
```

The list `YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES` is part of the `class Student`. Does it mean this list is stored somewhere in the database? If so, can it be accessed and modified during runtime?
Suppose I need to make this list dynamic depending on another model class. For eg:

```
class Edu_Level(models.Model)
   level = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
```

Each time my app creates a new `Edu_Level`, I want to add that level to the choice list in the other `Student` model. Assuming that they are both in the same app, is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: Its best that you create One-to-Many relationship instead of charfiels on students. Then you can do what you just said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a bad choice to set your' choices in the model, because each modification add a migration.

What you need to do is to create a `ModelForm` and set the choices from your model `Edu_level`

`EduLevel` has an `unique` Meta on `level`

```py
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    year_in_school = ModelChoiceField(queryset=EduLevel.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = ProfileDocument
        fields = ('year_in_school',)
```